# SQL query output results from one table into two columns

Tags: sql, group-by, count, pivot, conditional-aggregation

I have a set of data which I have queried and have extracted the right data, but would like the output to be in two different columns. The query is

```
(
    select month(observation_date) as month, count(total_snowfall_in) as snow 
    from weather_table 
    where city = 'Olympia' and year(observation_date) = 2019 and not (total_snowfall_in=0) 
    group by month(observation_date) order by month(observation_date)
) union all
(
    select month(observation_date) as month,  count(total_precip_in) as rain 
    from weather_table 
    where city = 'Olympia' and year(observation_date) = 2019 and not (total_precip_in=0) 
    group by month(observation_date) 
    order by month(observation_date)
)
```

What I would like to achieve is to have the data in a format similar to this:

| Month | Rain | Snow |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 0 |
| 2 | 12 | 34 |
| 3 | 23 | 9 |

The data is now shown under one column instead.

| Month | Rain |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 23 |
| 2 | 12 |
| 3 | 23 |

Comment: Please specify the output that you get now

Comment: @cooleck updated the answer above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT  MONTH(observation_date) AS month, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN total_snowfall_in <> 0 THEN 1 END) AS snow,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN total_precip_in <> 0 THEN 1 END) AS rain  
FROM weather_table 
WHERE city = 'Olympia' AND YEAR(observation_date) = 2019 
GROUP BY MONTH(observation_date) 
ORDER BY MONTH(observation_date);
```

Depending on the actual RDBMS that you use, the above code could be further simplified.